# Why are we allowed to divide by $x$ in the following differential equation?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, singularity

Suppose we have a second order linear differential equation $x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}-xy=xe^x$.Often we divide both sides by $x$ to get $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}-y=e^x$,and then proceed towards solution.Why does this make no harm as far as the solution of the differential equation is considered.We were trying to find $y=\phi(x)$ whose domain is $\mathbb R$.But,now we are finding a solution $y=\psi(x)$ whose domain is $\mathbb R-\{0\}$.Of course it is clear that the family of solutions $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ are equal except one has $0$ in domain and other does not ,I mean we can extend the other one to $\mathbb R$ by assigning some value at $0$ so that the extension is continuous.Does this make sense?Is this why we can divide by $0$ without worrying about losing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you have to worry about dividing by $x=0$. Having $x$ as a coefficient (especially of the highest-order term) is often a sign that you should expect some kind of weird behaviour of the solutions at $x=0$.

Comment: What kind of weird behaviour are you talking about,please write a bit more elaborately.

Comment: Well, for example it might happen that initial value problems with data at $x=0$ have infinitely many solutions, or no solutions, depending on what the data are.

Comment: please add an explicit example in you answer.

Comment: It would be a useful exercise to try to construct your own examples... But very well, consider $xy'+y=0$ with $y(0)=0$ vs. $y(0)=1$.